# Multiple Clocks At Once - Java

Tags: java

I know a question similar to this was asked and answered in javascript but I have an assignment in Java that involves displaying the time of single / multiple locations(selected from a list).

I have a certain amount of it built as you can see in my code below. However, I am getting stuck in so far as when I select multiple locations, the only clock that "ticks" is the last clock selected, the others just freeze at the time they were created.

Can someone have a look at my code below and see if they can give me some guidance?

Thanks

```
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.ListSelectionModel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class AssignmentV1 implements ActionListener/* ,ListSelectionListener */
{
    private String[] cities;
    private JButton addBtn;
    private JButton minusBtn;
    private JList cityList;
    private JPanel right;
    private JPanel displayArea;
    private JPanel[] clockDisplay;
    private long currentTime;
    private long cityTime;
    private int hourDiff;
    private String cityName;
    private String timeInFormat;
    private JLabel time;
    private JPanel topRight;
    private ArrayList<String> cityNamesList;
    private ArrayList<Long> cityTimes;

    public AssignmentV1() {
        JFrame appWin = new JFrame("World Time");
        appWin.setSize(400, 400);
        appWin.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        appWin.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        Font preferredFont = new Font("OCR A EXTENDED", Font.BOLD, 50);

        Container contentPane = appWin.getContentPane();

        displayArea = new JPanel();
        displayArea.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 2));

        JPanel left = new JPanel();
        left.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 1));

        JPanel topLeft = new JPanel();
        topLeft.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
        // adding of +/- buttons to display
        addBtn = new JButton();
        addBtn.setText("+");
        addBtn.addActionListener(this);
        topLeft.add(addBtn);
        minusBtn = new JButton();
        minusBtn.setText("-");
        minusBtn.addActionListener(this);
        topLeft.add(minusBtn);
        left.add(topLeft);

        // adding of list of cities to a scrollpane to add to display
        JPanel bottomLeft = new JPanel();

        setUpCities();
        cityList = new JList(cities);
        cityList.setSelectedIndex(0);
        cityList.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);
        JScrollPane scrollableList = new JScrollPane(cityList);
        bottomLeft.add(scrollableList);
        left.add(bottomLeft);

        right = new JPanel();
        topRight = new JPanel();
        clockDisplay = new JPanel[1];
        topRight.setLayout(new GridLayout(clockDisplay.length, 1));
        for (int i = 0; i < clockDisplay.length; i++) {
            clockDisplay[i] = new JPanel();
            cityName = cities[0].substring(0, cities[0].indexOf(","));
            hourDiff = Integer.parseInt(cities[0].substring(cities[0].indexOf(",") + 1));
            currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            cityTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + (1000 * 60 * 60 * hourDiff);
            clockDisplay[i].setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(cityName));
            time = new JLabel();
            time.setOpaque(true);
            timeInFormat = textAsTime(cityTime);
            time.setText(timeInFormat);
            clockDisplay[i].add(time);
            topRight.add(clockDisplay[i]);
        }
        right.add(topRight);

        displayArea.add(left);
        displayArea.add(right);
        contentPane.add(displayArea);
        Timer t = new Timer(1000, this);
        t.start();
        appWin.setVisible(true);

    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        cityTime = tick(cityTime);
        timeInFormat = textAsTime(cityTime);
        time.setText(timeInFormat);

        cityNamesList = new ArrayList<String>();
        cityTimes = new ArrayList<Long>();

        Object[] obj = cityList.getSelectedValues();
        Object source = e.getSource();
        if (source == addBtn) {
            topRight.removeAll();
            right.setLayout(new GridLayout(obj.length, 1));
            clockDisplay = new JPanel[obj.length];
            topRight.setLayout(new GridLayout(obj.length, 1));
            ArrayList<String> cityNamesList = new ArrayList<String>();
            ArrayList<Long> cityTimes = new ArrayList<Long>();
            for (int i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
                String temp = (String) obj[i];
                clockDisplay[i] = new JPanel();
                cityName = temp.substring(0, temp.indexOf(","));
                cityNamesList.add(cityName);
                hourDiff = Integer.parseInt(temp.substring(temp.indexOf(",") + 1));
                currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                cityTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + (1000 * 60 * 60 * hourDiff);
                cityTimes.add(cityTime);
                tick(cityTime);
                clockDisplay[i].setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(cityName));
                time = new JLabel();
                time.setOpaque(true);
                timeInFormat = textAsTime(cityTime);
                time.setText(timeInFormat);
                clockDisplay[i].add(time);
                topRight.add(clockDisplay[i]);
            }
            right.add(topRight);
        }
    }

    public void setUpCities() {
        cities = new String[] { "Accra,0", "Addis Abada,+3", "Adelaide,+11", "Algiers,-1",
                "Almaty,+6", "Amman,+3", "Amsterdam,+1", "Anadyr,+12", "Anchorage,-8", "Ankara,+2",
                "London,0", "Paris,+1" };
    }

    public String textAsTime(long currentTime) {
        long second = (currentTime / 1000) % 60;
        long minute = (currentTime / (1000 * 60)) % 60;
        long hour = (currentTime / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24;
        return String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", hour, minute, second);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new AssignmentV1();
    }

    public long tick(long cityTime) {
        cityTime = cityTime + 1000;
        return cityTime;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at actionPerformed(), there are a few problems there.  You need to setup the clock JLabels in a way that allows you to add more in the for loop, and still reference the already made JLabels each time the Timer fires.  Currently, you are just overwriting the value of the single 'time' JLabel each time you add a new clock, which effectively makes it impossible to call setText() (or anything else) on the previous labels.

Also, once this change is complete, make sure you remember to iterate over all the clocks and update their respective times.